# How can I successfully download a zip file in Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i've tried multiple ways to download a zip file but it just doesn't download. I'm able to unzip the files and view the contents normally so I know the zip isn't corrupted or anything

this is what i have tried so far

```
 app.post("/downloadFile/:file", function (req, res) {
  var archive = archiver('zip');
  function download(file){
    res.download(file)
  }
  console.log(req.path)
  urlpath = req.path.split("$");
  console.log(urlpath)
  urlpath.splice(urlpath,1);
  console.log(urlpath)
  var zip = new JSZip();
  for (const path in urlpath) {
    
    filename =urlpath[path].split("+");
    fakefilename = filename[0]
    filename = filename[1]
    console.log(urlpath[path]);
    var pFileData = fs.readFileSync("files/" + fakefilename);
    filename = decodeURI(filename)
    zip.file(filename, pFileData);
    
    
  }
  var zipName = urlpath[0].split("_")
  zipName = zipName[0]+ '.zip'

  zip.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./files/temp/' +zipName))
    .on('finish', function () {
        console.log("out.zip written.");
        res.download('./files/temp/' + decodeURI(zipName))
        console.log(zipName)
        console.log("response")
        var dfile = __dirname + '/files/temp/' + decodeURI(zipName)
        console.log(dfile)
        res.setHeader('Content-type','application/zip');
        res.download(dfile)
        res.sendFile(dfile)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please share what the error actually is. Too generic questions will unlikely get a response